# Getting error in jquery ajax "function not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am returning some values from jquery ajax. I am getting the result but with this I am also getting a error. Please first of all take a look at code

```
function get_CommentCount(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Profile/get_CommentCount',
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            handleData(data);
        }
    });
}
```

calling this function like this

```
get_CommentCount(function(output) {
    console.log('output', output)
});
```

Its give me error that `TypeError: handleData is not a function`. Please anybody tell me why I am getting this error. I have gone through the stackoverflow questions but I am not finding any solution for me. May be you find it duplicate but I post this question after surfing the stackoverflow.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code, where you call get_CommentCount

Comment: where you have added handleData function?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan please check I update the code

Comment: And where you have defined handleData.
I wonder you have problems with scope. Put a breakpoint into your success function and check 'this' value

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong with code.

Comment: @AzadChouhan from your code it seems to work.Please retry your code and see if there are errors before the function call.

Comment: @AzadChouhan your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/k87ncaje/. Could you show an example of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success function of your ajax you have wrote handle(data), and it is a function that you havent wrote any where may be, so this error is showing you that `TypeError: handleData is not a function` so you have define a function like

```
function handleData(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
```

and this will works for you.

Comment: OP is passing it as callback(parameter), its pretty valid code

Comment: He is passing the function as a callback.

Comment: Then, the error is getting only after function call

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are passing an anonymous function to get_CommentCount. Try with a normal function, it should work better.

Comment: The function is being passed as a parameter - it's completely valid.